# Intersection of tensor product of vector spaces whose intersection is $\{0\}$ is trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ and $W$ be subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space $U$ such that 
$$V \cap W= \{0 \}.$$
Let $A$ be a second vector space (possibly infinite).

Is it true that as subspaces of $A \otimes U$ we have

$$A \otimes V \cap A \otimes W = \{0\}?$$

My attempt at a proof:

Since $V \cap W = \{0 \}$ we have a split short exact sequence

$$0 \to V \overset{i}\to V \oplus W \overset{\pi}\to W \to 0,$$

where $i$ is the inclusion of $V$ in $U$ and $\pi$ the projection onto $W$.

Since $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces, they are flat modules over a field. Hence the sequence

$$0 \to A \otimes V \overset{id_A \otimes i} \to A \otimes (V \oplus W) \overset{id_A \otimes \pi}\to A \otimes W \to 0$$

is exact.

Since

$$A \otimes (V \oplus W) \cong A \otimes V \oplus A \otimes W$$

and by the definition of direct sum of vector spaces we have that $A \otimes V \cap A \otimes W= \{0\}$.

Does this proof work? I know that $\otimes$ is right exact, but shouldn't this work since $N \otimes M \cong M \otimes N$ for all modules $M$ and $N$?

Comment: Or does it suffice to say that $V+W= V \oplus W$ since $V \cap W= \{0\}$, and since $A \otimes (V \oplus W) \cong A \otimes V \oplus A \otimes W$ is must be that $A \otimes V \cap A \otimes W=\{0\}$?